# Cannot read property 'style' of undefined in useRef, react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, virtual-dom, use-ref

I'm trying to make a circle that will follow the mouse cursor. It is working fine but when I am trying to do the same in React it is showing that the style is not defiled. When I'm writing the code for the first time it is working fine but when I'm doing a refresh, it is showing the exact error mentioned before.

and using querySelector is also not working!

```
 import React, { useRef } from "react";

const Ball = () => {
  const ball = useRef();
  //   const ball = ballRef.current;
  //   console.log(ball, "app");

  let distanceX;
  let distanceY;

  let mouseX = null;
  let mouseY = null;

  let ballX = 0;
  let ballY = 0;

  let speed = 0.05;

  function left() {
    ball.current.style.left = ballX + "px";
  }
  function top() {
    ball.current.style.top = ballY + "px";
  }

  const animate = () => {
    distanceX = mouseX - ballX;
    distanceY = mouseY - ballY;

    ballX = ballX + distanceX * speed;
    ballY = ballY + distanceY * speed;

    left();
    top();

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  };

  animate();

  document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
    mouseX = e.pageX;
    mouseY = e.pageY;
  });
  return <div className="ball" ref={ball}></div>;
};

export default Ball;
```

**Expected Result:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noatw.png)

Comment: The react ref won't be defined on the initial render, so use a null check or optional chaining on the ref's current value. I.E `ball.current && ball.current.style.left` or `ball.current?.style.left`. Side note: You'll want to ***not*** attach document event listeners in the body of functional components like that, you will end up adding another listener each time the component is rendered. Use an `useEffect` to add the listener and return a cleanup function to remove the listener.

Comment: try to call `animate()` inside `useEffect(() => {...}, [])` and also the `addEventListener()`